# How to reslove the duplicate name error with swagger

Tags: editor, swagger

I need to define two fields named "description" and "type" in object with swagger 2.0,below is example,

```
  description:
   type: string
   description: ''
  type:
   type: string
   description: ''
```

However,an error "..Duplicated mapping key..." thrown out.Is there any solution to resolve this error since the field names are specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked in this [editor](http://editor.swagger.io/) and this object definition is working (based on some example yamls):

```
newPet:
  type: object
  properties:
    id:
      type: integer
      format: int64
    description:
      type: string
      description: ''
    type:
      type: string
      description: ''
```

Comment: Checked there's no constraint on duplicate name,another problem caused the error,thank you anyway.